# How to load the images from JSON object using react?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, reactjs

I have created the array of objects and i gave image path in that. I couldn't able to load the images from the array of objects using react and am getting an error like "module not found".I have stuck with this issue for past 2 days, kindly anyone help me out in fixing this issue or give me some suggestion for what to do next. I shared you the code snippet below:

```
    state = {
        data: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: "Mattel Uno Playing Card Game",
            imagePath: "../images/lenovo-p50.jpg"
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: "Hot Wheels Car",
            imagePath: "../images/lenovo-p51.jfif"
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            name: "Centy Toys Ambassador Car",
            imagePath: "../images/lenovo-p50.jpg"
          }
        ]
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Item Name</th>
                  <th>Item images</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {this.state.data.map((ele, i) => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={ele.id}>
                      <td>{ele.name}</td>
                      <td>
                        <img src={require(ele.imagePath)} width="200" />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  );
                })}
                <tr />
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        );
      }
```

How to load the images from the array of objects in react?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add `require` in src. When relative path is used it will go the images availale in your server but when url is given image will be loaded. You can find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

When using src as `/images/lenovo-p50.jpg` it will convert to `localhost:3000/images/lenovo-p50.jpg`